# How to get set value of promise as JavaScript attribute value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I have this code below in which I'm trying to return an array of objects with the following attributes:

```
0: {name: "Timmy", childID: "1", parentName: "Sally"}
1: {name: "Tommy", childID: "2", parentName: "Sully"}
2: {name: "Tammy", childID: "3", parentName: "Steve"}
```

Instead I am getting this:

```
0: {name: "Timmy", childID: "1", parentName: Promise}
1: {name: "Tommy", childID: "2", parentName: Promise}
2: {name: "Tammy", childID: "3", parentName: Promise}
```

I am trying to use the child ID to call the API and use the childID to a get a the name of a parent. I've tried using `promise.resolve`, `promise.all`, etc. I'm confused because `res` is of type `string` however when I call my `convert` function and log the array the attribute value of parent is always `Promise` and not the string value of the promise. Shouldn't the `.then()` method take care of that?

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!!

```
  const namesAndIDs = allUsers.map(({ name, childID }) => ({name, 
  childID}));

  console.log("name and child IDs", namesAndIDs);

  const convert = async (childID: string) => {
    const parent = await APIclient.parents.findOne({id: childID})
    // console.log(typeof parent.name)
    return parent.name as string;
  }

   const x = namesAndIDs.map(obj => ({ ...obj, parentName: 
    Promise.resolve(convert(obj.childID!).then((res) => {
    console.log(res); return res}))
}
));
```

Comment: Use `Promise.all` instead, to wait for each Promise to resolve before returning the new object

Comment: "Shouldn't the .then() method take care of that?" - no, a call to a promise's `then` method always returns a promise. Overall you can never get the result of a promise synchronously. See this [canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/5217142) about processing results obtained from an asynchronous API.